# Paginate a variable WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

If you can figure this one out you're my hero for life!

I'm working on a page that pulls all posts from a custom post type and displays them. At the top of the page is a filter form where users can select a Club and a date. The site will then filter through the content (using a WP_Query) to display what the user has selected. This works great!

However, if you try and paginate this content, something's not quite right! It's probably easier to show you...

[This link](http://seeyourself.b9media.co.uk/gallery/?club=bliss&inputdate=2013-07-18)

will display results for a specific club and date (limited to 2 posts per page), if you click through the pages on the bottom, you'll see that the images don't actually change and that `?paged=2` `?paged=3` etc. just get appended to the URL, no pagination logic is taking effect.

The code for the page is the following (pretty long I know)

```
      <?php 
            $club = $_GET['club'];

            $formdate = $_GET['inputdate'];
            $date = explode('-', $formdate);

            $paged2 = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'sell_media_item',
                'collection' => $_GET['club'],
                'include_children' => false,
                'year' => $date[0],
                'monthnum' => $date[1],
                'day' => $date[2],
                'paged' => $paged2,
                'posts_per_page' => 2
            ); ?>

            <?php $loop2 = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

            <?php if ( $loop2->have_posts() ) : while ($loop2->have_posts()) : $loop2->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="third gallery-third">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php sell_media_item_icon( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_sell_media_attachment_id', true ) ); ?></a>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <?php else: ?>

                <p>No images found.</p>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <!-- pagination php -->
            <?php
            if($loop2->max_num_pages>1){?>
                <?php
                  if ($paged2 > 1) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo '?club=' .$club. '&inputdate='. $formdate . '?paged=' . ($paged2 -1); //prev link ?>" class="page-numbers"><</a>
                                    <?php }
                for($a=1;$a<=$loop2->max_num_pages;$a++){?>
                    <a href="<?php echo '?club=' .$club. '&inputdate='. $formdate . '?paged=' . $a; ?>" <?php echo ($paged2==$a)? 'class="page-numbers selected"':'';?> class="page-numbers"><?php echo $a;?></a>
                    <?php
                }
                if($paged2 < $loop2->max_num_pages){?>
                    <a href="<?php echo '?club=' .$club. '&inputdate='. $formdate . '?paged=' . ($paged2 + 1); //next link ?>" class="page-numbers">></a>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <!-- end pagination php -->
```

There is a similar loop above this that states if no filter has been selected, then just get everything. Hence the `$loop2` variables.

I think I've covered everything. If you need any more info, feel free to ask away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing pagination loop to this:

```
    <!-- pagination php -->
    <?php
    if($loop2->max_num_pages>1){?>
        <?php
          if ($paged2 > 1) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo '?club=' .$club. '&inputdate='. $formdate . '&paged=' . ($paged2 -1); //prev link ?>" class="page-numbers"><</a>
                            <?php }
        for($a=1;$a<=$loop2->max_num_pages;$a++){?>
            <a href="<?php echo '?club=' .$club. '&inputdate='. $formdate . '&paged=' . $a; ?>" <?php echo ($paged2==$a)? 'class="page-numbers selected"':'';?> class="page-numbers"><?php echo $a;?></a>
            <?php
        }
        if($paged2 < $loop2->max_num_pages){?>
            <a href="<?php echo '?club=' .$club. '&inputdate='. $formdate . '&paged=' . ($paged2 + 1); //next link ?>" class="page-numbers">></a>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <!-- end pagination php -->
```

The only change I did was changing `?paged=` to `&paged=`

Comment: You have no idea how many days I've been staring at this...Thank you!